# Is it possible to remove certain characters in a particular column while creating an Athena table?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to remove certain unnecessary characters in a column, so that the data can be split into an array.
The original data is in json format like this:

```
{
    "id":"xyz",  
    "listL":"[\"N09jk\",\"KLpp1\"]",  
    "timestamp":"2019-01-04 05:33:02",  
}
```

I want to parse the `listL` attribute as an array like `[N09jk, KLpp1]`.
However given the current format, it takes the entire String as one element like this:

```
[["N09jk","KLpp1"]]
```

I was wondering if removing the characters `[ , ]`, and `"` while parsing the file and then splitting into array would work.

My create table query is:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.table (  
  \`id\` string,  
  \`listL\` array<string>,  
  \`timestamp\` timestamp   
)  
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'  
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
  'serialization.format' = '1'  
) LOCATION 's3://path/'  
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the table with the column `listL` as `string` and use `json_parse` to parse it as an array during querying:

```
SELECT
  id,
  json_parse(listL) as listL,
  timestamp
FROM table
```

You can also create a view so that you don't have to include the `json_parse` in every query:

```
CREATE VIEW table_with_list AS
SELECT
  id,
  json_parse(listL) as listL,
  timestamp
FROM table
```